# Concatenate A String to Each Element of a List

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Given a list in a single spreadsheet cell (Google Sheets), such as 1,3,7 how can I remake that list so that each element has a particular suffix or prefix?

For example, I've tried

```
=(join(",",split(concatenate("A","1,3,7"),",")))
```

but the result is `A1,3,7` instead of `A1,A3,A7` like I want.

Is there a non-scripting way to accomplish this?

Since this question can apply more broadly, is there a way, in google sheets or excel, to perform a function on every element of an array in memory, eg

```
FUN_ON_ALL_ELEMENTS(FUN(split(CELL,DELIM))
```

where FUN is applied to every split element of CELL?

Comment: Have you tried replace() and replace the "," with",A" ? You would need to combine it with your part to get the "1" done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to act on the elements of an array using `arrayformula`.

But your specific task is best carried out with `regexreplace` in Google Sheets. If A2 is a cell containing the comma-separated list, then

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "(^|,)", "$1A")
```

prepends A to each entry, the result being like A1,A3,A7.

And

```
=REGEXREPLACE(H2, "($|,)", "A$1")
```

appends A to each entry, the result being like 1A,3A,7A.

**Explanation**: the first formula says: add A after everything that is either a comma or the beginning of string. The second one is: add A before everything that is either a comma or the end of string.